# Folder search not returning results

Tags: api, search, graphql, make.com, integromat-apps

I'm building an integration with Sharepoint via Make (formerly Integromat). The native Make module for searching sharepoint does not identify the folder & returns no results. I have to enter a path relative to https://graph.microsoft.com - For instance https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children The query I input is just the folder name. What am I missing:
[Query example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH0qA.png)
[Sharepoint folder structure with duplicate folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCIcN.png)

I am also able to try a sharepoint API module within Make, but dont get results to search for a folder using this endpoint: /v1.0/myOrganizationdrive/root/children